# SAS statistical programming bindings into C#

Tags: c#, sas

I would like to **call some SAS instructions and get the results in my C# program** (like with the LINK SQL bindings).

Feed the SAS database from the C# program, get R² back from SAS, get ficher tests results, compare it with and alpha constant in my C# program, do graphical analysis in my C# GUI from the results i get in SAS, and so on...

**How can I call theses languages from eachother?**

For thoses who don't have a clue what I am talking about, read about [SAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_%28software%29).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [SAS Integration Technologies](http://www.sas.com/technologies/bi/appdev/inttech/index.html#section=3)? I believe there is support here for accessing SAS via C# (and various other platforms)